# Custom Rails initializer as a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have an initializer to load some data from a csv file to a global variable to be used in a model. Right now it looks like this:

```
...
XYZ = Hash[*CSV.open...]
```

Now I want to write an rspec spec for this initializer. I am using `rubocop-rspec` and it says that it is that `describe` should take not a string, but a class or a module (https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.1.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/DescribeClass).

Assuming this is reasonable, what are the options to convert initializer to a class?

There is an option to use `describe XYZ` but it does not seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Well, you could wrap `Hash[*CSV.open...]` into some helper class or module, say, `DataLoader`, cover it with tests and then invoke like `XYZ = DataLoader.do_stuff(filename)` in your initializer.

But there is one "issue" with this approach: the class will be really "dumb" (adding no custom logic at all, just wrapping a couple of methods from stdlib) and will be used in an initializer only - so will be called *just once*. I doubt all this additional boilerplate worth it.

So, I'd probably consider something simpler:

2) Just ignore (disable) this particular cop for this particular case. Conventions are good and `rubocop` is just great, but sometimes breaking the rules leads to a cleaner code than blindly following them. For example, I sometimes add tests for destructive rake tasks - in this case, I have to break this convention too, and I do it when necessary because it is still better than artificial workarounds for the sake of conventions... Need to test a minor piece of initializer's logic? Just do it :)